# Error in web.config with membership AD provider

Tags: asp.net, .net, activedirectorymembership

Try this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://mossdc02/, dc=expgroup, dc=ru" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
              type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
              System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
              connectionStringName="ADService"
              connectionUsername="domain\\userName"
              connectionPassword="password"/>
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <httpRuntime/>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In .cs file fire this:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {
            string userName = "domain\\userName";
            string password = "password";

            if (Membership.Providers["AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"].ValidateUser(userName, password)) {
                e.Authenticated = true;
            }
        }
```

Have this error:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:        Line 13:         
>   type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,  Line 15:
>   System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral,  Line 16:
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Help please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create your own `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`, you shall only config the web.config regarding the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
       name="MyADMembershipProvider"
       type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
       connectionUsername="testdomain\administrator" 
       connectionPassword="password"/>
  </providers>
 </membership>
```

Comment: Version should be 2.0.0.0, but not 2.0.3600. Ok. Thx!