# Form authentication against active directory works on IIS Express but errors when deployed to IIS asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a asp.net MVC application that is authenticating with a AD on the localhost. Everything is working fine when running it on IIS Express. But when running it on IIS 10 and windows server 2016 i get the following error from the web.config file. Any ideas what is causing this problem? I have the forms Authentication setting enabled for the site.

[image: error message in browser]

Here is my full web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://localhost/CN=Users,CN=Main,DC=xxx,DC=COM" />
    <!--<add name="xxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <!--xxx Site identifiers
    1 = xxx
    -->

    <add key="SignalRURL" value="http://xxx:53211/signalr" />
    <add key="xxxTempFolder" value="C:\xxx\" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LoggedOut" requireSSL="false" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" applicationName="xxx.xxx.WebClient" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" type="xxx.xxx.WebClient.Providers.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" />

      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
    <!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>-->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 322E7107-39D0-4959-9101-08AD3086E1F1-->
```

Comment: do you have AD role on that server? Is this string correct for that server? `LDAP://localhost/CN=Users,CN=Main,DC=xxx,DC=COM"`

Comment: I added xxx to hide sensitive information. But yes and it is working when running it on IIS Express

Comment: Im asking about `localhost` part in that string. Not sure but think it should be  AD server dns name or AD server IP

Comment: Ah.. well the AD is on the localhost where IIS is runnig

Comment: maybe then connection string requires username and password to connect? Just guessing, but as far as I remember IIS express is using user credentials, but IIS will run pool with network service account.

Comment: That could be something. Do you know the syntax for adding username and password?

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221146/312041), or you can run IIS pool from your credentials

Comment: @tym32167 thank you so much! you saved me from going all out Britney Spears on my mane :D I followed this link to change the identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: np, glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IIS Express have the permissions with the user it is running under, and within IIS the identity the application pool needs to be configured, before it is allowed to access the Active directory.

I uses the following guide to change the application pool identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Big thanks to @tym32167 for pointing in the right direction!